# Attaching click event to dynamic element getting fired for all parent elements too

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a dynamic table after getting data from server.

Each row of table has `a` tag for which i am trying to attach a click event.

below code block shows the creation of dynamic table.

```
function ProcessResponseData(Row) {
    var wrptr = CreateDynamicElement('tr', '', '');
    wrptr.append(CreateDynamicElement('td', Row.HeaderID, '')); // Row. Same property name mentioned in response class
    wrptr.append(CreateDynamicElement('td', Row.DealID, ''));
    wrptr.append(CreateDynamicElement('td', Row.CustomerName, ''));
    wrptr.append(CreateDynamicElement('td', Row.InvoiceNo, ''));
    wrptr.append(CreateDynamicElement('td', Row.ManufacturerID, ''));
    wrptr.append(CreateDynamicElement('td', Row.Make, ''));
    wrptr.append(CreateDynamicElement('td', Row.AssetModel, ''));
    var ancTd = CreateDynamicElement('td', '', '');
    ancTd.append(CreateDynamicElement('a', 'Validate', Row.HeaderID))
    wrptr.append(ancTd);

    wrptr.attr('WebserviceID', Row.WebServiceID);
    wrptr.attr('DealID', Row.DealID);
    wrptr.attr('MultipleProdID', Row.MultipleProdID);
    $('#tblSerialData').append(wrptr);
}
```

Below function creates the element.

```
function CreateDynamicElement(tagName, tagData, ActionAppendData) {

    var element = $(document.createElement(tagName));

    if (tagName == 'td') {
        tagData = (tagData != null ? tagData : '');
        element.text(tagData);
    }

    if (ActionAppendData != null || ActionAppendData != '') {
        element.text(tagData);
         //attaching the click event here to a tag    
        element.live('click', function (e) {
            ShowPopUp(ActionAppendData, this);
               e.stopPropagation(); // this has stopped the bubble but still it is getting attached to the tr rather than the a tag??
        });



    }
    return element;
}
```

The problem i am facing is the event is getting fired for the complete row. that is the event is getting attached to `tr> td> a`.

Any suggestion to resolve this.

Comment: google ``event.stopPropagation()``jquery

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thanks for your response , 'event.stopPropagation()' will stop the chaining of events . But is there any better way of attaching the event to dynamic element , so that we don't need to use this 'event.stopPropagation()'

Comment: event bubbles up to the parent element in DOM , there's no way IMO other than stopping propagation

Comment: ok , i have tried to use on,bind also for attaching event but it is giving the same response

Comment: Because your elements are dynamic, you could define the javascript handler function elsewhere and then just pass the name of the function to the event binding method.  That would clean up your code, but it won't affect the event propagation.

Comment: I think you need to create anchor tags separately in another if block - and if suitable don't attach click event handlers to your td and tr elements. Maybe this will work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.stopPropagation()`.  See [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Comment: ok So i have placed this code here element.live('click', function (e) {
            ShowPopUp(ActionAppendData, this);    e.stopPropagation(); 
        });      it has stopped the bubble, but it is appending it to tr rather than the a tag